# constantly having to re-type inputs each time function called inside other function

Tags: python

```
def print_intro():
    print('This program returns an excel file in the users downloads')
    print('that is the output of a special or cross+special')

def get_inputs():
    save_path = input('enter the file path of the folder that houses the excel file you want to work on, starting from C:, copy paste this ')
    file = input('enter the name of the entire file path of the excel file followed by .xlsx: ')
    #abs_path = input('enter the path up until python sns')
    abs_path = "C:\\Users\\mstevens\\python_test _Copy_for_pricing"
    decision = input("enter 'y' for prod cross and special, else hit enter and a special only is assumed")
    raw_key = input('enter the column name in the excel you want to join on. this needs to be exact')
    return save_path,file,abs_path, decision,raw_key



    # this function asks you whether to do prodcross+special or just special.
    # also asks you to enter the EXACT join key string as it appears in the excel
def cross_or_not():
     save_path,file,abs_path, decision,raw_key = get_inputs()
     join_key = raw_key.lower()
     if decision == 'y':
        if 'cross' in join_key:
            join_key = 'Clean Xrf Part No'
            
     else:
        decision == 'n'
        if 'star' in join_key:
            join_key = 'Newstar'
        elif 'sku' in join_key:
            join_key ='SKU'
        elif 'tracking' in join_key:
            join_key = 'Tracking No'
     return decision,join_key,raw_key



# Data Load prod cross ref query and/or special query and convert it to a dataframe
def dataLoad():
    decision,join_key,raw_key = cross_or_not()
    join_key = 'SKU'
    if decision =='y':
        
        with utils.db.db_erp() as cnxn:
            kyle_special = sqlQueries.to_df('kyle_special',cnxn)
        
        with utils.db.db_erp() as cnxn:
            cross = sqlQueries.to_df('prod_cross_ref',cnxn)
        
        data = pd.merge(kyle_special,cross[['SKU','Clean Xrf Part No']],on= join_key,how='left')
    
    else:
        with utils.db.db_erp() as cnxn:
            data = sqlQueries.to_df('kyle_special',cnxn)
    return data


def add_special_cols():
    special = dataLoad()
    #converts decimal.decimal column datatypes to datatype float
    special[['Avg. Cost w/ Tariff','Avg. Sell Prc.','Automann Prc.','Avg. Cost']]=special[['Avg. Cost w/ Tariff','Avg. Sell Prc.','Automann Prc.','Avg. Cost']].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
    special['Average Cost w/Tariff * 1.4'] = special['Avg. Cost w/ Tariff']*1.4
    special['(Avg cost*1.4 - Avg. Cost w/ Tariff)/Avg cost*1.4'] = ((special['Avg. Cost']*1.4) - special['Avg. Cost w/ Tariff']) / (special['Avg. Cost']*1.4)
    special['Avg. Sell Prc. *.99'] = special['Avg. Sell Prc.'] *.99
    special['((Avg. Sell Prc. *.99) - Avg. Cost w/ Tariff) / Avg. Sell Prc. *.99'] = ((special['Avg. Sell Prc. *.99']) - special['Avg. Cost w/ Tariff']) / special['Avg. Sell Prc. *.99']
    special['automann price *.99'] = special['Automann Prc.']*.99
    special['((automann price *.99) - avg cost with tariff) / automann price *.99'] = (special['automann price *.99'] - special['Avg. Cost w/ Tariff']) / special['automann price *.99']
    return special

# load file that needs to be crossed, convert it to a dataframe
def input_file(file):
    try:
        work_file = pd.read_excel(file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        print('there was a problem reading your excel file')
    return work_file
    

    
# clean the work file
def clean_work_file(file):
    dirty_file = input_file(file)
    decision,JoinKey,raw_key = cross_or_not()
    dirty_file= dirty_file.rename(columns={raw_key: JoinKey})
    if decision == 'y':
        dirty_file = dirty_file.applymap(lambda x: str(x))
        for i in range(len(dirty_file)):
            dirty_file[JoinKey][i].replace(' ','')
            dirty_file[JoinKey][i].replace('.','')
            dirty_file[JoinKey][i].replace('-','')
            dirty_file[JoinKey][i].replace('/','')
            dirty_file[JoinKey][i].replace("'",'')
    else:
           dirty_file = dirty_file[JoinKey].str.strip()
    clean_file = dirty_file
    return clean_file


def workfile_join(file):
    decision,JoinKey,raw_key = cross_or_not()
    work_file = clean_work_file(file)
    special = add_special_cols()
    if decision == 'y':
        work_file = pd.merge(work_file,special[['Clean Xrf Part No','SKU','Tracking Ln','Tracking No','Newstar','Description','Product Category','Product Sub-Category',
                            'Product Sub-Category 2','Tariff','Avg. Cost','Avg. Cost w/ Tariff',
                            'Std. Vendor Cost','Avg. Sell Prc.','Lowest Contract Prc.','SP1','Automann Prc.',
                            'Midwest Prc.','Average Cost w/Tariff * 1.4','(Avg cost*1.4 - Avg. Cost w/ Tariff)/Avg cost*1.4',
                            'Avg. Sell Prc. *.99','((Avg. Sell Prc. *.99) - Avg. Cost w/ Tariff) / Avg. Sell Prc. *.99',
                            'automann price *.99','((automann price *.99) - avg cost with tariff) / automann price *.99']],
                            on=JoinKey ,how='left')

    else:
        work_file = pd.merge(work_file,special[['SKU','Tracking Ln','Tracking No','Newstar','Description','Product Category','Product Sub-Category',
                            'Product Sub-Category 2','Tariff','Avg. Cost','Avg. Cost w/ Tariff',
                            'Std. Vendor Cost','Avg. Sell Prc.','Lowest Contract Prc.','SP1','Automann Prc.',
                            'Midwest Prc.','Average Cost w/Tariff * 1.4','(Avg cost*1.4 - Avg. Cost w/ Tariff)/Avg cost*1.4',
                            'Avg. Sell Prc. *.99','((Avg. Sell Prc. *.99) - Avg. Cost w/ Tariff) / Avg. Sell Prc. *.99',
                            'automann price *.99','((automann price *.99) - avg cost with tariff) / automann price *.99']],
                            on=JoinKey, how= 'left')
    return work_file
        

def write_into_excel(file):
    excel_doc = workfile_join(file)
    excel_doc = excel_doc.to_excel(file[:-5]+'-'+'special.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
    

def kyle_special_pipeline():
    print_intro()
    save_path,file,abs_path,decision,raw_key = get_inputs()
    write_into_excel(file)
    print('the program has executed, check downloads folder.')

kyle_special_pipeline()
```

Each time this program is run I have to resubmit the user input variables in the "get input" function. probably have to resubmit them each time the function is called in other functions. I thought if I defined them in the main function "kyle special pipeline" this would be avoided, apparently not. I just want to have to submit those inputs once for the program. any suggestions?

Comment: To store data between runs of a program you have to save it in a file.

Comment: if you want the inputs to be used several times, save them in a file the first time they are introduced, then further executions should look if the file exists. If so, fetch the data from there, if not ask the user for new inputs.  If you want a more professional way of doing that, use a database, like Redis.

Comment: perhaps im misunderstanding or mis-communicated, but the problem isnt that i have to enter the inputs once when running the program, its that i have to re-enter the inputs for each time the "get inputs" function is called thoughout the program eg when its called within other functions

Comment: then only call `get_inputs`  once at the beginning, store the information in variables and make the other functions use this variables instead of requesting the inputs again from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a call-once decorator to your `get_inputs` function.

The original `get_inputs` will only be called once. Its return values will be remembered, and those values will be returned for subsequent calls.

The implementation is quite simple:

```
def call_once(func):
    """A decorator ensuring only 1 call. Further calls return initial value."""
    first_call = True
    values = None
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """Execute wrapped function only once and return initial value."""
        nonlocal first_call, values
        if first_call:
            first_call = False
            values = func(*args, **kwargs)
            
        return values
    return wrapper

@call_once
def get_inputs():
    save_path = input('enter the file path of the folder that houses the excel file you want to work on, starting from C:, copy paste this ')
    file = input('enter the name of the entire file path of the excel file followed by .xlsx: ')
    #abs_path = input('enter the path up until python sns')
    abs_path = "C:\\Users\\mstevens\\python_test _Copy_for_pricing"
    decision = input("enter 'y' for prod cross and special, else hit enter and a special only is assumed")
    raw_key = input('enter the column name in the excel you want to join on. this needs to be exact')
    return save_path,file,abs_path, decision,raw_key
```

The `first_call` flag is set to true when the decorator is first applied to `get_inputs`. During each call, it is checked, and if it's true, the actual function is called and its return value is saved, the flag is set to false, and finally the value is returned.

`first_call` and `values` are declared as `nonlocal` inside the `wrapper` function. As they reside in the closure created by the `wrapper` function, changes to their values persist across function calls.

You could also use [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache%60)

Comment: your an absolute stud, thanks. ended up using the cache method. why make the implementation any harder then it needs to be. thanks again.